# Heap based permutation extremely slow for larger numbers

Tags: algorithm, recursion, permutation, pearson-correlation, heaps-algorithm

We are using Heap algorithm for generating permutations of an array a. . The generated permutations are passed to the printArr function,
which calculates the correlation coefficient between two arrays X and Y based on the current  permutation. This works as expected, however for larger numbers, e.g. more than 20.
Heap's permutation is exponentially slow. Any idea how can we significantly improve the Heap based permutation.

```
void printArr(int a[], int n, double X[], double Y[], int *diff, double corrcoeffO)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // cout << a[i] << " ";
    }

    // printf("\n");

    double corrcoeffHP = correlationCoefficient(X, Y, a, n);

    if (abs(corrcoeffHP) >= abs(corrcoeffO))
    {
        ++(*diffCount);
    }
}

void heapPermutation(int a[], int size, int n, double X[], double Y[], int *diffCount, double corrcoeff)
{
        if (size == 1)
    { 
        printArr(a, n, X, Y, diffCount, corrcoeff);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        heapPermutation(a, size - 1, n, X, Y, diffCount, corrcoeff);

        if (size % 2 == 1)
        {
            swap(a[0], a[size - 1]);
        }
        else
        {
            swap(a[i], a[size - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like it is slow because there are so many permutations. The solution is to look at fewer permutations. How to best do that depends on what you're really trying to do. Related, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/156738.

Comment: The number of permutations is ! so it is expected that generating all of them is going to take non-polynomial time.

Comment: @btilly Trying to figureout how to  look at fewer permutations to calculate correlation coeeficient and p-value

Comment: Also may be there is a non-recursive approach  to Heap's algorithm or some optimization within recursion of Heap's algorithm

Comment: If you want the maximum correlation between two arrays under any permutation... just sort both arrays.

Comment: What kind of p-value do you want? How is it defined? Would some kind of random sampling or approximation be good enough?